# How can I interact with a python class to update values in a javascript file?

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I would like to read a user input on a site, then perform calculations on that input using a python function, before displaying the result of that calculation.

The method I found whilst researching was to run a flask server locally, then call upon that server in my Javascript for the aforementioned result.

I have defined `update` in `app.py` using

```
@app.route('/update', methods=['POST'])
def update():
    data = request.get_json()
    value = data.get('value')
    
    # Perform the calculation based on the user input
    # Just a placeholder processing    
    new_value = value + 10
    
    state = {
        'result': new_value
    }
    return jsonify(state)
```

And in my `script.js` file, I have added an event listener to the submit button that would trigger when the user inputs data in order to change the display. The code is:

```
submitButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        // Get the user input value
        var value = userInput.value;
        
        // Make a POST request to the server with the user input
        fetch('/update', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ value: value })
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            // Update the HTML elements with the calculated result
            document.getElementById('display').textContent = data.result;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error: Failed to update values', error);
        });
    }
```

I have verified that the event listener is working as intended, since if I add the line `document.getElementById('display').textContent = value` right after I acquire the variable `value`, my website updates as intended.

It seems that there is a problem with my server somewhere, since currently, the display text is still a sample text that was left in the original html, and not the values calculated from user input.

I think the line `document.getElementById('display').textContent = data.result;` is not reached at all, since even if I change `data.result` to a hard coded value such as 5, the change is still not reflected. Finally, I have also tried `data.state.result`, but the problem persists.

Comment: Now is a good time to start familiarizing yourself with debugging tools available to you.  In your browser's development tools, are there any errors on the console?  In those tools, on the network tab, is the AJAX request made?  What is the server's response?  You need to narrow down the problem to either the client-side code or the server-side code and more closely debug that specific code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I took a look using the tools that you mentioned and I may see something that is causing the problem. The website is trying to read json from http://127.0.0.1:3000/update , when in reality my app.py is hosted on http://127.0.0.1:5000. I'm will now try to find a way to change the port that the website is reading from.

Comment: This case change first argument of fetch from `/update` to `http://localhost:5000/update`. My guess is your frontend is running on 3000, and using "partial" link defaults to this.

Comment: That is exactly what I have done, but now it looks like I am facing a much stickier problem, namely `Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/update' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy`. I am still researching to fix this issue right now.

Comment: @shao12138 the issue now is that you have requests going across origins. An origin is the protocol, host and port. So the protocols are the same (http), host is the same (local host/127.0.0.1) but the ports differ (3000 vs 5000). Browsers block these requests as part of the SOP (same origin policy). 

To resolve this the server has to respond to an OPTIONS request and state what methods and headers are allowed for a given origin (or fully permissive to any origin). 

More info here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: You can learn more about it with that link. I hate to just say “use a package” but sometimes keeping the momentum of what you’re doing can be helpful for learning. 

So for a simple resolution you can use the flask-cors package. 

https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ Scroll down to the simple usage section

Answer (score 1):

My own question got answered in the comments, but I thought I'd share it here for visibility. Credits to vampiire and David for the answer.

The problem is that (although, I am not sure if the cause is included in my original question or not) `app.py` is hosted on `127.0.0.1:5000`, but my javascript is attempting to read `/update` from `127.0.0.1:3000/update`. The fix for this was to simply change `fetch('/update'....` to the whole url, namely `fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/update'...`.

However, another problem will soon arise, since reading across ports is not permitted by default. The fix for this was to add a package in `app.py`

```
from flask_cors import CORS
```

then include the app inside CORS

```
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
```

Comment: Nice man. Happy to help and glad to see you’re unblocked. Good luck on the journey.